# ExpireAt is not working as expected, Spring RedisTemplate

Tags: java, spring, redis

I found a strange problem in prod that I have set a key with expire time by the command `StringRedisTemplate.expireAt`, but it is not expiring at all so I write the following test code and find `expireAt` method indeed not working as expected, but `expire` works:

```
    log.info("====================TEST====================");
    StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = context.getBean(StringRedisTemplate.class);
    for (int i= 0;i<10;i++) {
        String KEY = "TEST_LJJ_KEY_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"_"+i;
        long expireAt = System.currentTimeMillis() +500;
        String val = "expireAt@"+expireAt;
        Boolean firstSet = stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().setIfAbsent(KEY, val);//
        if (firstSet != null && firstSet) {//first set, then set an expire time
            Date expireAtDate = new Date(expireAt);
            stringRedisTemplate.expireAt(KEY,expireAtDate );//NOT WORKING!!!
            //stringRedisTemplate.expire(KEY,500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  // THIS WORKS
            log.info("===================={} expireAt {} ====================",KEY,expireAtDate);

        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(700);//wait it expire
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //CHECK.....
        log.info("after expireAT {} value --->{}, now:{} ",KEY,stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(KEY), System.currentTimeMillis());
        log.info("after expireAT {} pttl --->{}, now:{}",KEY,stringRedisTemplate.getExpire(KEY,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),  System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

Here's the output, as you can see, we have 500ms timeout for each key, and sleep 700ms(long enough to expire) after which we try get that value and find that it indeed exists, and when we get its ttl , I find that it's ttl is very very large, it seems that redis uses expire command rather than expireAt command.

```
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:47,819][main] >>> ====================TEST====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:48,099][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624387821_0 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:48.321+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:48,878][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624387821_0 value --->expireAt@1571624388321, now:1571624388878 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:49,192][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624387821_0 pttl --->1571624387231, now:1571624389192
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:49,402][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624389192_1 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:49.692+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:50,202][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624389192_1 value --->expireAt@1571624389692, now:1571624390202 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:50,451][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624389192_1 pttl --->1571624388645, now:1571624390451
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:50,647][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624390451_2 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:50.951+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:51,450][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624390451_2 value --->expireAt@1571624390951, now:1571624391450 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:51,706][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624390451_2 pttl --->1571624389892, now:1571624391706
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:51,862][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624391707_3 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:52.207+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:52,654][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624391707_3 value --->expireAt@1571624392207, now:1571624392654 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:52,898][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624391707_3 pttl --->1571624391172, now:1571624392898
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:53,061][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624392898_4 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:53.398+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:53,841][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624392898_4 value --->expireAt@1571624393398, now:1571624393841 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:54,118][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624392898_4 pttl --->1571624392350, now:1571624394118
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:54,291][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624394118_5 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:54.618+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:55,079][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624394118_5 value --->expireAt@1571624394618, now:1571624395079 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:55,344][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624394118_5 pttl --->1571624393565, now:1571624395344
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:55,498][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624395344_6 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:55.844+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:56,276][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624395344_6 value --->expireAt@1571624395844, now:1571624396276 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:56,506][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624395344_6 pttl --->1571624394835, now:1571624396506
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:56,658][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624396506_7 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:57.006+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:57,435][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624396506_7 value --->expireAt@1571624397006, now:1571624397435 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:57,672][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624396506_7 pttl --->1571624395991, now:1571624397672
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:57,825][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624397672_8 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:58.172+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:58,601][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624397672_8 value --->expireAt@1571624398172, now:1571624398601 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:58,836][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624397672_8 pttl --->1571624397162, now:1571624398836
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:58,988][main] >>> ====================TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624398836_9 expireAt 2019-10-21T10:19:59.336+0800 ====================
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:59,764][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624398836_9 value --->expireAt@1571624399336, now:1571624399764 
[INFO][2019-10-21 10:19:59,996][main] >>> after expireAT TEST_LJJ_KEY_1571624398836_9 pttl --->1571624398326, now:1571624399996
```

Comment: The code above works for me. Make sure that your local time is in sync with the Redis server time. Please also note that Redis expiry is not exact. Keys are seen as expired either if you touch the key on Redis or whenever Redis has gotten to the key to removing it. This can take on a Redis server with many expiries a while due to the expiration algorithm. The regular expiry time uses seconds as units of time, precise TTL uses milliseconds.

Comment: even though my local time is a bit not in sync with the redis server, how could it happen that the pttl is so so so large, it seems that redis uses expire rather than expireAt.

Comment: Your code asks for MICROSECOND resolution

Comment: @mp911de it's a typo, I have update the code and output, the same problem